# javascript - how to "fluent API" (also calling "chaining")?

Tags: javascript, methods

I am trying to understand is how to create call methods after a method call.

For example in jquery you have something like this:

`$("blah").data("data-id");`

How would I make :

`blah("cow").foo("moo");`

Where the mothods blah and foo just `console.log(value)`?

Comment: The blah function must return an object that has a function called foo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're referring to is a "fluent API" (also calling "chaining"). Your functions need to return the object that has the next method you want to call on it. For example,

```js
var obj = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.blah = function(v){ console.log(v); return self; };
        self.foo = function(v){ console.log(v); return self; };
    };

    var o = new obj();
    o.blah("cow").foo("moo");
```

See this article for more info: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4676-chaining-fluent-interfaces-in-javascript.html

Comment: Why rename this to self?

Comment: @NathanWilson, it's just a safe way to write code. `this` refers to the object calling the method and can, therefore, change based on how the method is called. For example, if you were to assign the method to a click event without creating a closure, `this` would refer to the object raising the event.

Comment: @NathanWilson, Consider the following example: `var x = new function(){ this.prop = 1;this.get = function(){ return this.prop; }; }(); var y = {prop:2, getX: x.get}; console.log(y.getX());` When you run this, it returns *2* when you may be expecting *1*. Compare that to this: `var x = new function(){ var self = this; self.prop = 1; self.get = function(){ return self.prop; }; }(); var y = {prop:2, getX: x.get}; console.log(y.getX());` which retains a reference to the original object and returns *1* as expected.

Comment: @adam0101 ever heard of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: @ThomasRuiz, yes, I'm not saying there aren't other ways of doing it, but if I'm creating something that is going to be reused by another developer, I prefer to code in a way where they won't need to have explicit knowledge  of how to implement it. And also, IE8 doesn't support `bind`.

Comment: @adam0101 browser compability for IE8 is useless now that windows XP support has been dropped by Microsoft. Besides, using `bind` inside your function won't require to use it afterwards. ES5 is now almost 6 years old, you know.

Answer (score 1):

The function blah has to return an object with a method foo. Here is an example:

```
function blah(blahArg) {
    return {
       foo: function (fooArg) {
            console.log(blahArg, fooArg);
       }
    };
}

blah("cow").foo("moo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the object that contains the functions when the function is done. then you can chain them.

Here is an example from what I made a while back:

```
// I extend a class with a new function
HtmlObject.prototype.stop = function () {

    clearInterval( this.updater );
    this.animationQue   = [];
    this.updater        = undefined;

    // Then return the object that initially called the function
    return this;
};
```

So I could use it like object.stop().nextfuntion();

Also, In JQuery the `$` is simply a shortcut to a JavaScript function.

I did the same in my test, but then with `_`. I must admit it is not as nifty as JQuery but:

```
var _ = function ( selector, context ) {
    var el = new xyvLib();
    // This will simply return a collection of HtmlObjects (of which you can find a snipet above)
    return el.fn.select( selector, context );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.foo` on the result of `blah()` only when `blah()` returns an object which accepts the method `foo` on it.

A simple example would be like this:

```
function foo(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
function blah(value) {
    console.log(value);
    return { foo: foo } 
}
```