# How to implement more than one method in JS es6 class?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class of validations that I have created in JS:

```
let test = new Validator(req.body);
```

Now I want to test something, maybe that a specific key in this object is 2-5 char length, I would do it like this:

```
let myBoolean = test.selector("firstName").minLength(2).maxLength(5);
// firstName is like: req.body.firstName
```

And how this could be done in the class?

**EDIT**

I made something like this:

```
audit.isLength({selector: "from", gte: 2, lte: 35})

class Validator {

  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.isValid = true;
  }

  isExists(sel) {
    if (typeof this.obj[sel] === "undefined") return false;
    return true;
  }

  isLength(info) {
    let sel = this.obj[info.selector];
    if (typeof sel === "undefined") return false;
    if (info.gte) {
      if (sel.length<info.gte) return false;
    }
    if (info.lte) {
      if (sel.length>info.lte) return false;
    }
    if (info.gt) {
      if (sel.length<=info.gt) return false;
    }
    if (info.lt) {
      if (sel.length>=info.lt) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `selector` method needs to return *something* that has a `minLength` method that in turn returns *something* that has a `maxLength` method. It doesn't matter at all whether `selector` is part of a `class` or not.

Comment: Note that your proposed api won’t work - presumably, minlength should also return boolean? But it can’t since it should also return sth on which you can call maxlength. You will need a terminating call that returns the final result. Befor you reinvent the wheel, you may want to look at something like https://github.com/rjperes/FluentValidationJS if only to get some inspiration

Answer (score 2):

Create a class with [**fluent methods**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966627/javascript-how-to-fluent-api-also-calling-chaining)/[**chainable methods**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730334/how-to-make-chainable-function-in-javascript), that return `this`, which is an instance of the class itself and when you finally run validation according to the rules, call `.validate()`, which will act as a final method to return the result:

```js
class Validator {
  constructor (body) {
    this._body = body;
  }
  
  selector(str) {
    this._selector = str;
    return this;
  }
  
  minLength(num) {
    this._minLength = num;
    return this;
  }
  
  maxLength(num) {
    this._maxLength = num;
    return this;
  }
  
  validate() {
    // run your validation logic here and return true or false accordingly
    return true
  }
}

const req = { body: 'body' };
const test = new Validator(req.body);
const myBoolean = test
  .selector('firstName')
  .minLength(2)
  .maxLength(5)
  .validate();
  
console.log('rules:');
console.log(test);
console.log(`result: ${myBoolean}`);
```

Comment: WTH is a fluid method?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this - assign the object to validate to a property on the instantiation, return `this` from each validating call, and when validating, assign to an `isValid` property on the object (if it isn't already `false`). Note that you need to access the `isValid` property finally in order to retrieve the boolean.

```js
class Validator {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.isValid = true;
  }
  selector(sel) {
    this.sel = sel;
    return this;
  }
  minLength(min) {
    if (this.isValid) this.isValid = this.obj[this.sel].length >= min;
    return this;
  }
  maxLength(max) {
    if (this.isValid) this.isValid = this.obj[this.sel].length <= max;
    return this;
  }
}

const test = new Validator({firstName: 'foobar'}); // 6 chars: invalid
console.log(test.selector("firstName").minLength(2).maxLength(5).isValid);
const test2 = new Validator({firstName: 'fooba'}); // 5 chars: valid
console.log(test2.selector("firstName").minLength(2).maxLength(5).isValid);
const test3 = new Validator({firstName: 'f'}); // 1 char: invalid
console.log(test3.selector("firstName").minLength(2).maxLength(5).isValid);
```

Comment: I guess this is one of the few cases where `this.isValid = this.isValid && …;` could be cleaner than `if (this.isValid) this.isValid = …;` :-)

Comment: What about undefined in the selector?

Comment: @Raz You might set the `isValid` property to `false` in the constructor if the `obj` doesn't exist, or when `selector` is called and `this.obj[sel]` doesn't exist (or isn't a string, whatever you need)

Comment: And what happen if the selector is: "when.date.start" ?
The this.obj[this.sel] will be undefined anyway, isnt it?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key) if you're worried about the 

That (usually) wouldn't be a sane property name to exist on an object, because it's very confusing given the dot operator. But, like I said, you can test for the existence of a key when `selector` is called, and set `isValid` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This is the builder pattern (sort of). You'll probably want to define a separate class that has a minLength and maxLength function. Those functions will set some state on the builder, and return either `this` (the builder its self), or a new builder that's a copy of `this`. Then you'd have some finalize function on the builder, which looks at the state, handles all the logic based on the min/max, and returns a boolean.