# How can I Create a Function for Infinite Calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript where there will be an infinite call to greet(). The expected outcome is to have the greetings concatenated with each call.

```
console.log(greet('hello').greet('world').greet())
```

the output of the above should give  `Hello world`
and there might be infinite `greet('string')`

My initial implementation looked like this:

```
let greet = function (a) {
  return  function (a) {
        return function (c){
          return c ? (b + " " + c ) : (a + " " + b);
        }
  }
};
```

However, the output is not as expected. I am facing some issues in the implementation and would like some help in resolving them. Can someone help me fix this issue? Thank you in advance."

Comment: Try greet("hi")("wow")("yay")

Comment: @TrevorDixon. problem statement is to solve ```console.log(greet('hello').greet('world').greet())```

Comment: Just trying to open your mind :D

Answer (score 6):

Basically, have a function that returns an object with a function inside which in turn invokes the global function that returns an object... etc

```js
let greet = a => ({
    greet: b => b ? greet(a + ' ' + b) : a
})

console.log(greet('hello').greet('world').greet())
```

Comment: Thanks, @gog.  I also found a way. I was trying to do without the arrow function

Answer (score 2):

The issue in your code is that you are using the variable b inside the innermost function, but it's not defined in the scope of that function. Also, you are declaring a function with the same name a in the inner function, which shadows the outer a parameter.

Here's a corrected version of the code:

```
let greet = function (a) {
  let b = a;
  return function (c) {
    if (c) {
      b = b + " " + c;
    }
    return {
      greet: function (d) {
        return greet(b + (d ? " " + d : ""));
      }
    };
  };
};
```

With this code, you can call greet multiple times and concatenate the greetings with each call. For example:

```
console.log(greet('hello').greet('world').greet());
// Output: "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for fluent chaining in JavaScript. You can achieve this approach by creating your own custom class and keep returning `this`:

```js
class Greeter {
  content = '';
  greet(string) {
    this.content += (this.content.length ? ' ' : '') + string;
    return this;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.content;
  }
}

const greeter = new Greeter();
const output = greeter
  .greet('I')
  .greet('can')
  .greet('do')
  .greet('this')
  .greet('forever')
  .toString();
  
console.log(output);
```

You can check other possibilities by searching it. For example on [Stackoverflow are similliar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966627/javascript-how-to-fluent-api-also-calling-chaining).

Comment: Thanks for the  answers i am trying to end the call by ```.greet()```

Comment: Potential issue  - mutable shared state. https://jsbin.com/nibizeroju/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding to my issue.
i also came up through some implementation with  traditional function expressions

here is my solution

```
 let greet = function (a) {
  return {
    greet: function (b) {
      return b ? greet(a + " " + b) : a;
    }
  }
};
```